# Sas - Proc Hadoop - "There is not enough space on the disk"

Tags: hadoop, sas

I am trying to transfer text file from windows server to linux server using sas proc hadoop using copyfromlocal and out option.
Everything worked fine, i transferred files upto size 1gb per file to the maximum.
But suddenly the code is not working, no changes were done to the code, it throws the error:
**java.io.IOException: There is not enough space on the disk**

I could not now transfer even files with size 250MB. Just to confirm whether the code is not changed from the initial creation, I tried using the same code again and transferred about 1KB file and it is working fine. But could not transfer files bigger in size, like in MBs.

There is enough space available both in windows and linux server

Has anyone have seen this issue before, Could anyone help on this
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Issue got resolved, the c drive of SAS server was full though other drives where data is found were having more spaces, now spaces are cleared and the code is working fine